# Spark sql how to explode rows with hierarchy type tables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

### Source Data Table

`/Company/Engineering/DataTeam   45`

`/Company/Engineering/Mobile     50`

### Output Data Table

`/Company  45`

`/Company/Engineering  45`

`/Company/Engineering/DataTeam 45`

`/Company  50`

`/Company/Engineering  50`

`/Company/Engineering/MobileTeam 50`

---

So my question is basically by looking at the above source and output data table, the transformation from the source to output data table, how can I achieve it with spark sql.

I couldn't use an UDF because with UDFs you can't return rows. So my next step was to create a data frame in memory and appending rows by using an UDF. But the problem with this approach is that, the data frame is going to have over a billion rows and I am not sure if thats even feasible.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this with spark sql ?

Answer (score 0):

In UDF, you can return a Seq[String], which can be exploded to get multiple rows.

Check this out:

```
scala> val df = Seq(("/Company/Engineering/DataTeam",45),("/Company/Engineering/Mobile",50)).toDF("a","b")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: string, b: int]

scala> df.show(false)
+-----------------------------+---+
|a                            |b  |
+-----------------------------+---+
|/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|45 |
|/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |50 |
+-----------------------------+---+

scala> val udf_hier_str = udf( (x:String) => x.split('/').drop(1).scanLeft(""){(acc, next) => acc + "/" + next}.drop(1) )
udf_hier_str: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,ArrayType(StringType,true),Some(List(StringType)))

scala> df.withColumn("gen_hier",explode(udf_hier_str('a))).show(false)
+-----------------------------+---+-----------------------------+
|a                            |b  |gen_hier                     |
+-----------------------------+---+-----------------------------+
|/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|45 |/Company                     |
|/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|45 |/Company/Engineering         |
|/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|45 |/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|
|/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |50 |/Company                     |
|/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |50 |/Company/Engineering         |
|/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |50 |/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |
+-----------------------------+---+-----------------------------+


scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, without udf()

```
val df = spark.sql("""
select '/Company/Engineering/DataTeam' a,45 b union
select '/Company/Engineering/Mobile',50 b
""")
df.show(false)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

+-----------------------------+---+
|a                            |b  |
+-----------------------------+---+
|/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|45 |
|/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |50 |
+-----------------------------+---+
```

Solution-1: using posexplode()

```
spark.sql(""" 
select *, concat_ws("/",slice(split(a,"/"),1,x+1)) z from (
select a,b, posexplode(split(a,"/")) (x,y) from df
) where x<> 0
""").show(false)

+-----------------------------+---+---+-----------+-----------------------------+
|a                            |b  |x  |y          |z                            |
+-----------------------------+---+---+-----------+-----------------------------+
|/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|45 |1  |Company    |/Company                     |
|/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|45 |2  |Engineering|/Company/Engineering         |
|/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|45 |3  |DataTeam   |/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|
|/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |50 |1  |Company    |/Company                     |
|/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |50 |2  |Engineering|/Company/Engineering         |
|/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |50 |3  |Mobile     |/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |
+-----------------------------+---+---+-----------+-----------------------------+
```

Solution-2: Using transform() higher order function.

```
spark.sql(""" 
select * from (
select a, b, explode_outer(z) z2 from (
select a,b, transform(split(a,"/"), (x,i) -> concat_ws("/",slice(split(a,"/"),1,i+1))  ) z from df
) ) where length(z2) > 0
""").show(false)

+-----------------------------+---+-----------------------------+
|a                            |b  |z2                           |
+-----------------------------+---+-----------------------------+
|/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|45 |/Company                     |
|/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|45 |/Company/Engineering         |
|/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|45 |/Company/Engineering/DataTeam|
|/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |50 |/Company                     |
|/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |50 |/Company/Engineering         |
|/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |50 |/Company/Engineering/Mobile  |
+-----------------------------+---+-----------------------------+
```